# How to set java delimiters with ", /*, \*

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I am writing a code that is going to read string and has to know if it is made up of letters or is a punctuation or not. for eq: (string refers to ( and string as 2 different entities.

I have already set a delimiter with

```
String DELIM = "[\\s\\-\\.\\'\\,\\?\\,\\_\\@\\#\\(\\)\\;]+";
```

but code still treats *, *, /* as string made of letters rather than punctuation.

How could I edit my Delim to be able to change that?

Comment: add code snip you tried

Answer (score 1):

Inside square brackets block `[here]` you don't need to escape too much.
Regex `[\\s-.'?,_@#();*\\/]+` perfectly catches any delimiter in string
`aa bb-cc.dd'ee?ff,gg_hh@ii#jj(kk)ll;mm*nn/oo`.

Here is a Java snippet:

```
String regex = "[\\s-.'?,_@#();*\\/]+";
String text = "aa bb-cc.dd'ee?ff,gg_hh@ii#jj(kk)ll;mm*nn/oo";
String[] split = text.split(regex);
for (String s : split) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:
aa
bb
cc
...

You could also go the other way and catch anything that is NOT a latter or a digit with regexp:
`[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`.